# Comparing arbitrary small $\epsilon>0$ with taking the limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

We have the standard statement in analysis that

> i) For all $\epsilon>0$ and two **fixed** $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ it holds $|b-a|<\epsilon \Leftrightarrow$ $a=b$.

However, sometimes it is the case that $|b-a|<\epsilon$ holds while $a$ and $b$ vary with a decreasing $\epsilon$. So we have something like:

> ii) "For all $\epsilon>0$ and two functions of $\epsilon$, $f_a(\epsilon),f_b(\epsilon)$ it holds $|f_b(\epsilon)-f_a(\epsilon)|<\epsilon$".

As an example: $f_b(\epsilon)$ might be a limit point or $f_a(\epsilon)$ and $f_b(\epsilon)$ might be Darboux sums.

---

I am not 100% sure if I have understood properly the difference between both statements. May be someone can tell me if the following two statements are right:

1.) I cannot apply the statement i) to ii) and say $f_b(\epsilon)=f_a(\epsilon)$. A simple explanation would be that in the context of ii) we don't have fixed numbers because $f_a(\epsilon),f_b(\epsilon)$ vary. A more rigourous explanation can be made if I apply the limit to $|f_b(\epsilon)-f_a(\epsilon)|<\epsilon$:
$$\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0}|f_b(\epsilon)-f_a(\epsilon)|\leq\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0}\epsilon =0.$$ This means that the limit of $f_b(\epsilon)-f_a(\epsilon)$ exists. However, this doesn't automatically imply that from some small $\epsilon$ onwards we have $f_b(\epsilon)=f_a(\epsilon)$. It *might* be the case that $f_b(\epsilon)=f_a(\epsilon)$ but it is also possible that $f_b(\epsilon)\neq f_a(\epsilon)$ for all $\epsilon$.

2.) If I apply the explanation regarding the limit to statement i) it means that:
$$\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0}|f_b(\epsilon)-f_a(\epsilon)|=\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0}|b-a|\leq\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0}\epsilon =0.$$
As $f_b(\epsilon)$ and $f_a(\epsilon)$ are constant functions and the limit of $f_b(\epsilon)-f_a(\epsilon)$ exists, it must be $f_b(\epsilon)=f_a(\epsilon)$ for all $\epsilon$, so $b=a$.

Are my thoughts in 1.) and 2.) correct? Any comments or further explanations are welcome :)

Comment: i) doesn't seem like a standard statement in analysis to me - have you seen it written in exactly that form somewhere?

Comment: (i) is better written along these lines: "Fix $a,b\in \Bbb{R}$. Then it holds that ($\forall \epsilon>0$, $|a-b|<\epsilon) \iff a=b$", and the second one is better phrased as "let $f_a,f_b:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ be functions, and suppose that for every $\epsilon>0$, $|f_a(\epsilon) - f_b(\epsilon)| < \epsilon$".

Comment: @MatthewTowers, yes this statement appears in exactly that form in our material/lecture notes, followed by a  comment which denotes this technique as a classical analysis argument. What is surprising about that?

Comment: I find it surprising because it's such a confusing way to phrase the result. "For an arbitrary $\epsilon$" makes it sound like there is just a single $\epsilon$ under consideration, but in fact, as peek-a-boo says above, the right statement requires an inequality to hold for every positive $\epsilon$ - I'd never use "arbitrary" in this way.

Comment: @MatthewTowers, ah ok I know what you mean. I have edited the question, I hope that it is clearer this way.

Comment: I still wonder if the odd way it's now phrased is connected to your confusion. When I read that sentence it sounds like the false claim $\forall \epsilon (|a-b|<\epsilon \iff a=b)$ instead of the correct statement $(\forall \epsilon |a-b|<\epsilon) \iff a=b$

Comment: @MatthewTowers I have read it like $(\forall \epsilon~|b-a|<\epsilon)\Leftrightarrow a=b$. However, it is not so much the statement i) itself that confuses me but rather how to connect i) and ii) logically.